# Interceptor not getting initialized and invoked with SpringBoot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, interceptor

I've a Spring-Boot application that is packaged as a war with tomcat dependency as provided (so I've both options - use the packaged .war to run within embedded container after launching it via java -jar command AND also to run on a standalone servlet container).

Below is my App main class

```
package com.mycompany.edsa.dgv.proxysvc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
//import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import  org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

import com.mycompany.edsa.dgv.proxysvc.interceptor.DGVProxySvcRequestInterceptor;

//import com.mycompany.edsa.dgv.proxysvc.config.ConfigExtension;

@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource("classpath:dgv-proxy-svc-spring-ctx.xml")
//@Import(ConfigExtension.class)
public class DGVProxySvcAppMain extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DGVProxySvcAppMain.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(DGVProxySvcAppMain.class);
}

@Bean
public DGVProxySvcRequestInterceptor dgvProxySvcRequestInterceptor() {
    DGVProxySvcRequestInterceptor dgvProxySvcReqInterceptor = new DGVProxySvcRequestInterceptor();
    return dgvProxySvcReqInterceptor;
}


@Bean
public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter adapter() {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
            System.out.println("Adding interceptors");
            registry.addInterceptor(dgvProxySvcRequestInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/*");
            super.addInterceptors(registry);
        }
    };
}
```

}

My Interceptor class below:

```
package com.mycompany.edsa.dgv.proxysvc.interceptor;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

@Component
public class DGVProxySvcRequestInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {

        /* Put in the code here to validate user principal before passing control to the controller */

        //BXPPrincipal principal = (BXPPrincipal)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
        //Map<String, ?> result = principal.getAttributes();
        System.out.println("Inside DGVProxySvcRequestInterceptor...");
        return super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

}
```

However, on launching the application (I launch through `spring-boot:run` maven goal and using Eclipse IDE), I do not see my interceptor getting registered in the console logs.
I tried launching it in debug mode with a breakpoint at the `public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry)` method and I see that control comes at this point and the sysout message `"Adding interceptors"` get logged on console and also the `registry` contains my `DGVProxySvcRequestInterceptor` in its encapsulated ArrayList but not sure why there is no message on console mentioning anything about initialization of this interceptor bean.
Moreover, on invoking my service, I do not see sysout message `"Inside DGVProxySvcRequestInterceptor..."` that has been put into my interceptor class' `preHandle` method (which confirms that the interceptor didn't get invoked).

Can someone pls help me out in finding what configuration mistake I might be doing?

Pls note - I tried extending my main class with `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` instead of `SpringBootServletInitializer` and overriden the `addInterceptors` method to add my interceptor. In that case my interceptor gets initialized well (I can see on console logs) and also gets invoked when I invoke my service uri.
So this tells me that something is not correct with my configuration when I try to use `SpringBootServletInitializer` (I've to use this initializer as I need to package my code as a war that can run on a standalone servlet container).

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/pointers !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the fix. Had to use the `ant` like url pattern to match the requests:

```
registry.addInterceptor(dgvProxySvcRequestInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/**");
```

My original configuration was all good; did not require any change except for the above url pattern.

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue. 
`@SpringBootApplication` scans all the component from the current package only. In order to scan other package, we need to specify package in `@ComponentScan`.
**For Example**

```
package com.main;
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
     //Code goes here.
}
```

Now i want interceptor to be register, which is neither in `com.main` not `com.main.**`, its available in `com.test` package.

```
package com.test.interceptor
@Configuration
public class InterceptorConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    HeaderInterceptor headerInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(headerInterceptor);
    }
}
```

In above case, Spring Boot won't register `HeaderInterceptor` in context. In order to register, we must explicitly scan that package.

```
package com.main;
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.*") //Which takes care all the package which starts with com.
@ComponentScan({"com.main.*","com.test.*"}) //For specific packages
public class Application {
     //Code goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using java 8, the recommended implementation is WebMvcConfigurationSupport.  WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated.

Comment: for some reason, the moment I switched from  WebMvcConfigurerAdapter to WebMvcConfigurationSupport, my requests started to be intercepted.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc 
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter  {  
    // @Bean resolvers , etc

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(new DGVProxySvcRequestInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/controller/action/*");
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe using @EnableWebMvc will avoid using Spring's auto configurations i guess. Is there no workaround to add interceptor without overriding auto configurations ?

Comment: Also, tried the above suggestion; doesn't help. The controller gets invoked first and then the interceptor !

Comment: did you replace your action urls properly 'addPathPatterns'